# Is there any documentation on wix extension class

Tags: wix, wix-extension

can anyone point me to documentation/help on wix extension classes. I have look at the simple pre-processor example on the wix site, but I am looking for information on how to exend light.exe not just candle.exe/

Comment: The best documentation may unfortunately be just going through the wix source for an extension that already exists.

Comment: oh that's looks problematic as I cant see one that does what I am trying to do; also I am not sure what many of them are doing.  where is the best place to ask questions?

Comment: You can try here but I dont know how active it is. Was very popular back in the day http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/. You can also try getting in contact with some of the people who work on wix through their github https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3